# Statistics of slope in individual polygons (asset) on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, slope

I have a single shapefile with multiple polygons, uploaded to GEE as an asset. I am trying to find the mean slope (using SRTM elevation imagery) in each of the polygons, on GEE. However, I get only one mean slope value for all the polygons.

My code is as below. Do I have to use .filter() when importing the asset? If so, which one and how do I indicate the regions to be the different polygons? Or do I change the parameter for the Geometry: when calculating mean slope?

```
// Load the SRTM image.
 var srtm = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003'); //Calling SRTM 30m images

// Apply slope algorithm to an image.
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm); 

//Scale and Projection
var scale = srtm.projection().nominalScale();
print('SRTM scale in meters', scale); //see Console tab in the right section 
of screen- 30.92208 m
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', srtm.projection()); //EPSG:4326 
is WGS 1984, look at right section of screen in the Console tab

// Load polygon shp border
var x= ee.FeatureCollection('ID')
Map.addLayer(x)

//Displaying slope for country
var elevregion= srtm.clip (x);
var slopecountry= ee.Terrain.slope(elevregion); //Slope is in degrees
//var slopecountry_radians= slopecountry.divide(180).multiply(Math.PI) 
//converting to radians 'divide the slope by 180, multiply the result of 
that by π
Map.addLayer(slopecountry); //to view

// Compute the mean elevation in the polygon.
var meanDict = slopecountry.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
geometry: x,
scale: 30
});

// Get the mean from the dictionary and print it.
var mean = meanDict.get('slope');
print('Mean slope', mean);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't clip the image and use reduceRegions to compute the means.  It will apply the reducer to each feature in the collection independently.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var srtm = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');     
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);    
var scale = srtm.projection().nominalScale();

print('SRTM scale in meters', scale);    
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', srtm.projection()); 

var x= ee.FeatureCollection('ID');
Map.addLayer(x);

var elevregion= srtm;    
var slopecountry= ee.Terrain.slope(elevregion); 

Map.addLayer(slopecountry);     

var meanDict = slopecountry.reduceRegions({
  collection: x,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 30,
});


print('Mean slope', meanDict);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: medianDict,
  description: 'Feature Collection Slope',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```